# Type '{ children: Element; ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have problem with fowardRef in ReactJS it seems that everything is ok, but got an error:

```
Type '{ children: Element; ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SectionContentT & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SectionContentT & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'. [2322]
```

Here is my code:

```js
interface LoadingT {
  isLoading?: number;
}

const SectionStyledContent = styled.div<LoadingT>...;

interface SectionContentT {
  isLoading?: boolean;
}

const SectionContent = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, SectionContentT>(({children, isLoading}, ref) => {
  return (
    <SectionStyledContent isLoading={isLoading ? 1 : 0} ref={ref}>
      {!isLoading && children}
    </SectionStyledContent>
  );
});

...

const resizerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

<SectionContent isLoading={isLoading} ref={resizerRef}>
  <p>something</p>
</SectionContent>
```

I've got TypeScript errors when using the `SectionContent` component, inside the component file types are correct and TS doesn't complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue while I was writing the question (using SO as [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)). But it may be valuable to others.

The problem was that children were not defined in my props. Before adding the `forwarRef` I was using this code:

```js
interface SectionContentT {
  isLoading?: boolean;
}

const SectionContent: React.FC<SectionContentT> = ({children, isLoading}) => {

};
```

and was expecting the `forwardRef` will have the same signature but it's not. It requires props to have children. So my code was supposed to be:

```js
interface SectionContentT {
  isLoading?: boolean;
  children: ReactElement
}

const SectionContent = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, SectionContentT>(({children, isLoading}, ref) => {

});
```

The error message shows exactly what the problem is, but I didn't figure out that immediately that's why I'm adding this, so others will not waste time.